# Java Error - NoClassDefFoundError while running a java program from command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac, javacompiler

Team,

I am struck with a basic error for quite sometime. Can someone pin point what i am missing here.

Created a simple java program (which would connect to a socket and send a message). Code mentioned below

```
package client.sever.socket.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

/**
 *
 * @author prem
 */
public class Clientprog {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /** Define a host server */
                String host = "localhost";
    /** Define a port */
                int port = 19997;

    StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
    String TimeStamp;
    System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");

    try {
      /** Obtain an address object of the server */
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      /** Establish a socket connection */
      Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
      /** Instantiate a BufferedOutputStream object */

       BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.
          getOutputStream());

      /** Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional character
       * encoding.
       */
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

      TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
      /*String process = "Calling the Socket Server on "+ host + " port " + port +
          " at " + TimeStamp +  (char) 13;*/
      String process = "01234"+  (char) 13;

      /** Write across the socket connection and flush the buffer */
      osw.write(process);
      osw.flush();

      /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
      /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
       * incoming socket streams.
       */

      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.
          getInputStream());
      /**Instantiate an InputStreamReader with the optional
       * character encoding.
       */

      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

      /**Read the socket's InputStream and append to a StringBuffer */
      int c,d=0;
      try
      {
          if(isr.ready())
          {
          }
          else
              System.out.println("NO RESPONSE");
      while (( (c = isr.read()) != 13) && d<4)
      {
        instr.append( (char) c);
        System.out.println("Inside Loop - "+instr);
        d++;
      }}
      catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
      {
          System.out.println("OOM ERROR - "+e);
          System.out.println(instr);
      }
      /** Close the socket connection. */
      connection.close();
      System.out.println(instr);

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
     System.out.println("Unknown Host Exception: " + e);
    }
    catch(ConnectException e)
    {
     System.out.println("ConnectException: " + e);
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
     System.out.println("Exception: " + e1);
    }
    }
}
```

Compliling and running with IDE - Successful.

If tried with Command prompt, it fails with below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Clientprog
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Clientprog
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Clientprog.  Program will exit.
```

Tried setting classpath also. The .class file is also located in the same path as .java file.

The steps followed in Command prompt is below for reference.

**Step 1**

C:\Users\prem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src\
ent\sever\socket\example>set Path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin"

**Step 2**
C:\Users\prem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src\
ent\sever\socket\example>set HomePath="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32"

**Step 3**

C:\Users\pre00185\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src\
ent\sever\socket\example>javac Clientprog.java

**Step 4**
C:\Users\pre00185\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src\
ent\sever\socket\example>java Clientprog

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Clientprog
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Clientprog
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Clientprog.  Program will exit.

Comment: I referrred to many links and other SO questions similar to this, but still the issue is not resolved. So, i have posted this question and steps i followed.

Comment: Try setting the class search path on the command line to include the current working directory also known as "."; e.g.: java -cp . Clientprog

Comment: javac client/sever/socket/example/ClientProg.java in src path
and 
java client.sever.socket.example.ClientProg

Comment: @anuraggupta, i dont understand what you are trying to say here

Comment: @chrislott, i tried that option. It did not work

Comment: i mean that; to run go to the location "C:\Users\pre00185\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src" and then hit 
"java client.sever.socket.example.ClientProg" after compilation and it'll work

Comment: @anuraggupta, I tried. It is still the same. The .class file of Clientprog is in the same path as that as .java file. But still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the classpath when running the java command as well as reference you class with its fully qualified class name.

```
SET CP="C:\Users\pre00185\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Client Sever Socket Example\src"
java -cp %CP% client.sever.socket.example.Clientprog
```

This assumes your class file is in the same location as your source.  Adjust this as needed.

Comment: I tried. The .class file of Clientprog is in the same path as that as .java file. But still i am getting this error.